# VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception:

Tags: python

When I run the code, I got this error:

[ERROR:0] global /io/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap.cpp (116) open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception:

OpenCV(4.1.2) /io/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_images.cpp:267: error: (-215:Assertion failed) number < max_number in function 'icvExtractPattern'

Please show me how to fix it. Thank you very much.

And this is my source code:

```
    # Program for finding the location of a person based a difference images 
# The video file name should be specified.


import os
from typing import Dict, List, Tuple

import datetime
from datetime import datetime

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#import sklearn
#from sklearn import metrics
#from sklearn import neural_network
#import sklearn_util

import cv2

def guess_location(src):
  index = np.array([i for i in enumerate(src)])
  index_sum_sort10 = index[index[:, -1].argsort()][::-1][0:40].T
  location = int(np.average(index_sum_sort10[0]))
  return location

def calculate_location(src):
  row_max_location = guess_location(np.sum(src, axis=0))
  col_max_location = guess_location(np.sum(src, axis=1))
  return (row_max_location, col_max_location)

#
# Read video frames from a usb-camera / video file,
# and find the location of the person

#

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

v_filename= '/dev/compact-module/Videodata/2021/03/22/1720_00_006686/entity_video_1616401200006.mp4'
#'/media/qf-zhao/68A01144A0111A60/GrayDiffVideo/Image2019_11_18_08_40_00.avi'
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(v_filename)

th_change = 150
th_value  = 30
location_back=(0,0)
while(cap.isOpened()):

  ret, frame = cap.read()
  diff=cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
  diff[diff<th_value]=0

  if np.max(frame) < th_change:
    location=location_back
  else:
    location = calculate_location(diff)
  print("location:", location)

  cv2.circle(frame, location, 10, (0,0,255), -1)
  cv2.imshow('Result image', frame)

  location_back=location

  if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break


cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```